# When to use "in respectively"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I see some people use "in respectively" instead of "respectively". For instance when I googled it with quotes, I saw the following [example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23122577).

> ...Physicians overestimated the risk in respectively 42.7%, 54.1% and
>   21.3%. However, very high risk was underestimated in respectively 38.1%, 
>   22.0% and...

"In" is used because "respectively" is used before the data given ?

How about my sentence ? Are both okay to use?

> The chart shows students' answers to a survey in which they were asked
>   their favorite subject. It can be seen that over  a quarter of the
>   students prefer computer science which is followed by English and
>   Spanish. Student who study English, Spanish and Chinese comprise about
>   half of whole students, studying the subjects % 18, %15 and % 15
>   **in** respectively.

Comment: Your first example doesn't make any sense.  "in respectively X, Y, and Z **of what ?**".  Your second example, it's just "respectively", not "*in* respectively"

Comment: These "some people" you see using "in respectively," are they non-native speakers? Because that's what it sounds like.

Comment: @Robusto I do not know if they are native speakers or not. As I said, when I search with quotes as " in respective", some results show up on Google referring to some books. For example, I cited my example apparently from a medical writing.

Comment: I guess you are looking at [*LDL-cholesterol target values and actual values in patients with type 2 diabetes (T2D) uncontrolled on oral antidiabetic monotherapy: the lipid results of the French ESCALADE survey.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23122577). You should cite the source and include the entire paragraph in your question. Because earlier in the same paragraph "respectively" is used correctly. Also this is the only such example of "in respectively" that I saw in the search. I think it is a typo. or grammar error.

Comment: @JohnFeltz the original site showed up is : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23122577

Comment: @user3169 Thanks. How about this page :http://www.europarl.europa.eu/thinktank/en/document.html?reference=EPRS_BRI(2016)593559

Comment: Abstracts of scientific papers can be length-limited; in which case the authors may throw out normal grammar for the sake of getting more data in.  I'd be cautious using abstracts as examples of good writing.

Comment: Additional information should be added to your question.

Comment: @user3169 It's also used correctly in the sentence which follows the error. Likewise, in the 'europarl' link the *in* doesn't take *respectively* as its object, but "X% of...*: "in [respectively] 26% and 38% of EU countries." I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is taking a typo as model for the proposed sentences.

Answer (score 3):

"In respectively" is, itself, not idiomatic. It can show up in some sentences but not as in your examples.  Here is how it could appear:

> Physicians overestimated the risk in, respectively, 42.7%, 54.1%, and 21.3% of subject Groups A, B, and C.

"Respectively" matches the percentages to their related groups.  It means that the values are *written* in the same order as the names -- 42.7% relates to Group A, etc.

Meanwhile "in" actually maps to "subject groups" (note the important comma between "in" and "respectively").  We can (and probably should) rewrite as follows:

> Physicians overestimated the risk in Groups A, B, and C, by, respectively, 42.7%, 54.1%, and 21.3%.

Comment: good point!  That comma allows the mapping of two lists respective to one another.

Answer (score 1):

"In respectively" is incorrect grammar.  You have shown that people have used it, but that does not make it right.  A native speaker would just use "respectively". Putting an adverb within a two-word prepositional phrase makes no sense.  Not that it fits even with "in", but can you think of any other prepositions which would contain "respectively"?

- out respectively ?
- from respectively ?
- of respectively ?
- beyond respectively ?

I just looked up "in" and see that it can also be used as an adjective or adverb. Neither helps the grammar of "in respectively" though.

Perhaps non-native speakers started using this because of a false association with "irrespectively". That is just speculation, though.